# C# DataTable within Powershell Script

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am able to get a C# code sample to run within a Powershell v2.0 script as follows:

```
$Source = @"
using System;

namespace CSharpInPowershell
{
    public static class Sample
    {
        public static void TryDataTable()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp

[CSharpInPowershell.Sample]::TryDataTable()
```

However, I am getting an error when trying to add a data table:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data

$Source = @"
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace CSharpInPowershell
{
    public static class Sample
    {
        public static void TryDataTable()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp

[CSharpInPowershell.Sample]::TryDataTable()
```

The error I get is the following:

> Add-Type : c:\Users(userid)\AppData\Local\Temp\qbefurwr.0.cs(2) : The
>   type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'System'
>   (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   c:\Users(userid)\AppData\Local\Temp\qbefurwr.0.cs(1) : using System;
>   c:\Users(userid)\AppData\Local\Temp\qbefurwr.0.cs(2) : >>> using
>   System.Data; c:\Users(userid)\AppData\Local\Temp\qbefurwr.0.cs(3) :
>   namespace CSharpInPowershell At line:1 char:9
>   + Add-Type <<<<  -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (c:\Users(userid)...bly reference?):CompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
>
> Add-Type : Cannot add type. There were compilation errors. At line:1
>   char:9
>   + Add-Type <<<<  -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

As you may see, I tried to add a reference using `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Data`.  My goal is to be able to use C# code samples within a Powershell script.  I know I could re-write this all in Powershell, but I'm trying to get this type of scripting to work.

How can I get the assembly reference for `System.Data` recognized within the C# code?

UPDATE:  Thanks to @SomeShinyObject, I have the following working script:

```
$Source = @"
using System;
using System.Data;

namespace CSharpInPowershell
{
    public static class Sample
    {
        public static void TryDataTable()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp `
         -ReferencedAssemblies System.Data, System.XML

[CSharpInPowershell.Sample]::TryDataTable()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the `ReferencedAssemblies` parameter.

```
#When I tested, System.XML also needed to be added for it to work so I included it
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharpVersion3 -ReferencedAssemblies System.Data, System.XML
```